# How to experimentally cool a nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, nuclear-physics

Its possible to cool atoms experimentally (i.e. reducing their individual momenta) through laser cooling getting matter composed of these atoms to do some strange things (Ex: superfluids and bose-einstein condensates).

But suppose you wanted, just for fun to make them EVEN COLDER. I came across: http://www.int.washington.edu/users/bertsch/general_interest/scientific_american_1983.pdf which describes (albeit in a very pop-sci way) the existence of vibrations in the nuclei of atoms.

How could one experimentally damp these nuclear vibrations and cool them to a ground state?

(I suppose one could use neutrino's to cool off stuff involving the weak-interaction)

Comment: The neutrinos due to interacting only weakly cannot be"used" in any coherent way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the exception of meta-stable nuclear isomers (look for a mass-number with an 'm' at the end as in [technium-99m](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technetium-99m)) almost every nucleus you meet is already in the ground state for that isotope. Most excited nuclear states decay very quickly, so that there is no chance of collecting a laboratory sample of nuclei in those states. The meta-stable states are the exception.

Of course some isotopes which are in their own ground state can get to an even lower energy state by some radioactive decay process, which they do. Eventually.

Short answer to the question asked: there is no means of cooling the nucleus.

Comment: the decay process you refer to here, would be one of the conventional ones which would change the underlying # of neutrons and protons?

Comment: Meta-stable states have a route to decay to the same isotope (and may also have a route to decay to some other isotope as in the example of technium-99m). The other are the usual set of isotope changing decays.

Comment: So if i understand correctly outside of meta-stable cases, once an atom's electrons have been cooled to their respective ground state, then: without changing the isotope it is not possible to cool the atom further ?

Comment: The energy and state of a physical system is effectively partitioned into different regimes that don't always communicate with one another, and I think that you are confusing them. The thing that this cooled in, say, a laser trap is the motion of atoms taken as a whole. The atoms have internal degrees of freedom associated with their electron structure and with their nuclear structure. Neither of those communicate with the motional degrees of freedom at low energy. Nor, for the most part, do the electronic degrees of freedom communicate with the nuclear ones (excepting electron-capture).